# Subquery as offset argument - LAG() Function in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2, sql-function

I would like to ask a question. Generally, we know that LAG() function can be expressed as ***LAG(column expression, Offset,[default value]) OVER(ORDER BY . . .)*** . Does anyone know if the offset can be ***a subquery*** in db2?

I try to insert a subquery and to cast the result as integer with no result.

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual : https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=expressions-lag-lead-functions

Quote:

> offset
>
> Non-negative integer ***constant*** defining an offset from the position of the current row
>
> ...
>
> ***Literal*** integer

So, no, you can't use a sub-query

Comment: @ParisK.Patsogiannis - SO guidance says to not extend questions, and especially not to use comments to do so.  Please open a new question, and include some example data to demonstrate what you want to do: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Informix is not Db2..